# multiple buttons in fragment, how to redirect to a different layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment with 8 buttons and i want that each button leads me to a different layout but i have no idea how to do that i only have one button working but i don't know how to put in the other seven can anyone help me please?

this is what i have so far:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagina_principal, container, false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.btnazul).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Rutas_azul.class));
        }
    });

    return view;


}
```

Comment: can you add error log?

Comment: Exactly how you have done it here... Change the R.id.btnazul to the corresponding button id and perform the action accordingly

A good practise would be declare the buttons and have the Fragment implement OnClickListener. In the OnClick method do a switch-case on the view id and perform the corresponding action

Comment: repeat the same with different 2nd parameter for the Intent constructor

Comment: if u want to switch another activity having different layout, then why not to use Intent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single click listener for all buttons:

```
private final View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                // do stuff
               break;
            case R.id.button2:
                // do stuff
               break;
            case R.id.button3:
                // do stuff
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your onCreateView

```
view.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(mListener);
view.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(mListener);
view.findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(mListener);
```

do for all 8 buttons.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! you saved my life! :D

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Alejandro Gurrola

Make your fragment implement the View.OnClickListener

Then implement the onclcick method as below.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            //Start activity one
            break;
        case R.id.button2
            //Start activiy two
            break;
        // Do this for all buttons.
    }
}
```

Then in the onCreateView() method of your fragment do the following.

```
Button button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
// Do this for all the buttons
```

.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
//Do this for all the butons.
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: i have done this but the onCreateView doesn't recognize the view in view.findViewById

Comment: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagina_principal, container, false); is your view

Comment: i did what you said and  now the error is diferent :/ i can't paste the code because of the lenght

Comment: Post the error at least so that we can understand the root cause@AlejandroGurrola